# Turn 512 x 3 dataframe into 128 x 4 x 3 matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have this dataframe here. I want to convert the last 3 columns (Colour, Number, Shape) into a 128 x 4 x 3 matrix using the values in the grouping variables 'trial' and 'Card' as guides.

```
trial Card Colour Number Shape
1      1     1      1      0
1      2     0      1      1
1      3     0      1      0
1      4     1      1      1
2      1     1      0      0
2      2     1      1      0
2      3     0      1      1
2      4     1      1      0
.
.
.
```

My goal is to have a 3D matrix like this one below, where the first dimension are trials, the second dimension are each of the 4 cards, and the third dimension are 1. Colour 2. Number 3. Shape:

```
, , 1

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    1    0    0    1
  [2,]    1    1    0    1


, , 2

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    1    1    1    1
  [2,]    0    1    1    1


, , 3

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    0    1    0    1
  [2,]    0    0    1    0
```

This is my code at the moment:

```
#generate fake data
data<-matrix(rbinom(128*12, 1, .5), ncol=12)
trial<-seq(from = 1, to = 128)

data<-cbind(trial,data)
data<-as.data.frame(data)

colnames(data)[2] <- "Card1_colour"
colnames(data)[3] <- "Card1_number"
colnames(data)[4] <- "Card1_shape"
colnames(data)[5] <- "Card2_colour"
colnames(data)[6] <- "Card2_number"
colnames(data)[7] <- "Card2_shape"
colnames(data)[8] <- "Card3_colour"
colnames(data)[9] <- "Card3_number"
colnames(data)[10] <- "Card3_shape"
colnames(data)[11] <- "Card4_colour"
colnames(data)[12] <- "Card4_number"
colnames(data)[13] <- "Card4_shape"

#get data into 512 x 5 format
card_match<-tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = -trial, 
                    names_to = c('Card', '.value'), 
                    names_pattern = 'Card(\\d+)_(.*)')

#Here I've tried to reshape the last 3 columns of card_match without the 'trial' and 'card' columns but it hasn't worked
card_match2<-card_match%>% select(3:5) # get only last 3 columns
card_match_final<-array(unlist(card_match2), dim=c(128,4,3)) #get 128x4x3 matrix
```

The last line is my attempt to reshape the dataframe into a 3d matrix, which it has done, but the values are not in the order I want them to be. How may I alter this code, potentially using the 'trial' and 'card' variables to guide the reshaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(cbind(Colour,Number,Shape) ~ trial + Card, data)
#, ,  = Colour
#
#     Card
#trial 1 2 3 4
#    1 1 0 0 1
#    2 1 1 0 1
#
#, ,  = Number
#
#     Card
#trial 1 2 3 4
#    1 1 1 1 1
#    2 0 1 1 1
#
#, ,  = Shape
#
#     Card
#trial 1 2 3 4
#    1 0 1 0 1
#    2 0 0 1 0
```

Tested on the smaller `data` as shown in the start of the question:

```
# generate smaller fake data
data <- read.table(text="
trial Card Colour Number Shape
1      1     1      1      0
1      2     0      1      1
1      3     0      1      0
1      4     1      1      1
2      1     1      0      0
2      2     1      1      0
2      3     0      1      1
2      4     1      1      0",
header=TRUE)
```